# Order SQL query records by frequency

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there any way to order the records you select from an SQL query by how often a certain value appears in a column? For example: If there are five records where column = 'value1', three where column = 'value2', and two where column = 'value3', is there a way to make the results display 'value1' first, then 'value2', and finally, 'value3'?

Comment: In your example, do you want *three* rows in the final result (the distinct "column" values ordered by count), or *ten* rows (all "column" values ordered by value frequency)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT   `column`,
         COUNT(`column`) AS `count`
FROM     `table`
GROUP BY `column`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

Quick PoC:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `table` (`id` SERIAL, `column` char(6) NOT NULL, KEY `column_idx`(`column`));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table` (`column`) VALUES ('value1'), ('value1'), ('value1'), ('value1'), ('value1'), ('value2'), ('value2'), ('value2'), ('value3'), ('value3');
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM `table`;
+----+--------+
| id | column |
+----+--------+
|  1 | value1 |
|  2 | value1 |
|  3 | value1 |
|  4 | value1 |
|  5 | value1 |
|  6 | value2 |
|  7 | value2 |
|  8 | value2 |
|  9 | value3 |
| 10 | value3 |
+----+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT   `column`,
    ->          COUNT(`column`) AS `count`
    -> FROM     `table`
    -> GROUP BY `column`
    -> ORDER BY `count` DESC;
+--------+-------+
| column | count |
+--------+-------+
| value1 |     5 |
| value2 |     3 |
| value3 |     2 |
+--------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want *all* rows, but ordered by the frequency of values in some column `` `col` ``, you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id SERIAL, col VARCHAR(16));
-- INSERT so that `id` does not match frequency of values under `col`
INSERT INTO tbl (col) VALUES ('value1'), ('value2'), ('value3'),
                             ('value1'), ('value2'), ('value3'),
                             ('value1'), ('value2'),
                             ('value1'),
                             ('value1');

    SELECT id, tbl.col
      FROM tbl
INNER JOIN (  SELECT col, COUNT(1) AS freq
                FROM tbl
            GROUP BY 1) derived
           USING (col)
  ORDER BY derived.freq DESC;
```

which will produce

```
+----+--------+
| id | col    |
+----+--------+
|  4 | value1 |  <-- highest incidence
|  7 | value1 |
|  1 | value1 |
|  9 | value1 |
| 10 | value1 |
|  5 | value2 |
|  8 | value2 |
|  2 | value2 |
|  6 | value3 |  <-- lowest incidence
|  3 | value3 |
+----+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```