# Frequency based sort in sql

Tags: sql, sorting, frequency

I have a problem with sorting sql tables.

I have this:

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| a    |    1 |
| b    |   3  |
| c    |    4 |
| d    |    3 |
| e    |    2 |
| f    |    2 |
| g    |    2 |
| h    |    1 |
+------+------+
```

And i need to have this:

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| e    |    2 |
| f    |    2 |
| g    |    2 |
| a    |    1 |
| h    |    1 |
| b    |    3 |
| d    |    3 |
| c    |    4 |
+------+------+
```

I tried with COUNT(), but it work only with GROUP OF that's why it isn't what i need.

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for all responses.

Comment: Don't be shy.  What is the mysterious sort order that you want?

Comment: I want to have most popular product type on top of sorted table, but i want not table with grouped products by product type.

Comment: The OP has attempted to explain the sort order in the title.  S/he seems to want the `col2` values ordered by their frequency, so "2" is first because it appears three times.

Comment: which DB you are using?

Comment: Similar question that has an answer for generic SQL - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467997/order-sql-query-records-by-frequency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If database supports OVER clause then it is quite simple:

```
SELECT t.id, t.value
FROM t
ORDER BY count(*) over (partition by value) DESC
```

See SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce805/3

Answer (score 1):

I see.  You want to sort by the frequency of the values.  Most dialects of SQL support window functions, so this does what you want:

```
select t.col1, t.col2
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by col2) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
order by cnt desc, col2;
```

Another way of writing this uses a `join` and aggregation:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select col2, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
      group by col2
     ) tt
     on t.col2 = tt.col2
order by tt.cnt desc, t.col2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your sort order, you want to first have the the rows with the most occurrences of Col2 value, etc...

Here is a suggestion for getting your result:

```
SELECT T.Col1, T.Col2
FROM YourTable T
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable T2
WHERE T2.Col2 = T.Col2) DESC, T.Col2 DESC, T.Col1 ASC
```

Hope this will help.